# Data warehouse for AD dates

Tags: mysql, date, data-warehouse, dimensions

We're creating a historic archive for a world history database and we need a date lookup table which references all dates in AD. How to go about creating the values for this table - from 1AD to 2011 as YYYY/MM/DD? Database is MySQL.

Problems:

1. I'm using Excel to pre-populate the dates, then import into MySQL as: YYYY/MM/DD but Excel doesn't recognize years like 0007, 0008, etc so I can't auto-copy cells to generate dates. I have to manually do it and this will take days to go from 1AD to year 2011 as YYYY/MM/DD.
2. Leap years were introduced on 1752. If I programmatically generates dates how do I handle cases prior to 1752 with no leap years? It will generate wrong dates.

My table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `dates` (
      `date_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `format` char(10) NOT NULL,
      `century` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `decade` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `year` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `month` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `week` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `day` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `month_year` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `week_year` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `week_month` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `day_year` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `day_month` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `day_week` int(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`date_id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Why is a normal `datetime` type column insufficient? Are there events that have multiple dates or date ranges?

Comment: Yes, this is a in depth world history DB for analytics. Think about any event like a world war, a revolution, etc all span multiple days, weeks, months, years, etc. Plus we have historic beliefs like people believed in witches right up to the 19-20th century, this spans over thousands of years.

Comment: Even for date ranges, all you'd need is two `datetime` columns (start/finish)... Your approach still smells funny to me. Can you justify why `datetime` column(s) are insufficient? The worst part about this is that every day you need a new record in your `dates` table... you would have to generate dates in the future through at least, say, 9999AD. And worst yet, most of this table would be full of duplicate data (century, for example, is generally useless - you can determine this at runtime, no need for a database row to tell you this).

Comment: Here is the usecase: An invention was discovered on jan 6, 1412, another on mar 6, 1519. We want to show people analytic that on the 6th day of the month in X date range these X inventions were invented in Y location or whatever filters are used. Another is on a fixed date like mar 11, 1012 45 events occurred (4 inventions, 17 revolutions, etc). All of these events span mutiple tables due to the unique and large number of events. I have not seen live database but was told by the team just from 1 AD to 5AD there are over 220 million events.

Comment: Plus if we don't use a lookup table we need to calculate this at runtime that date (mar 2, 1912) is month 3, day 2 of the month and day 63 of the year, decade xxxx of the century. So if i want to output all events on the 4th decade of the 2nd century i have to d all this at runtime then search vs just searching from already defined date lookups.

Comment: @yardy as far as I can tell, all this can be done using `datetime` fields. mySQL may not have a ready-made function for the century thing, but it does for everything else. See [mySQL Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: @Pekka and @Mike Atlas: This type of approach is standard data-warehouse dimension-table design: denormalizing the database by storing redundant information and indexing the extra columns for faster queries. It's much faster to query all Mondays (for example) if there is a weekday field than to use a weekday(datetime) function. For each datum (or "fact") you then store only the date_id. In any case, the question is about how to generate the dates, not whether this storage format is good :)

Comment: Yes, how can i generate the dates. Really don't want to do it manually 1 by 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use something like this SQL (using my own table structure, not the one you had though):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_dimension;
CREATE TABLE time_dimension (
        id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  -- year*10000+month*100+day
        db_date                 DATE NOT NULL,
        year                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        month                   INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 12
        day                     INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 31
        quarter                 INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 4
        week                    INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 52/53
        day_name                VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'Monday', 'Tuesday'...
        month_name              VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'January', 'February'...
        holiday_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (holiday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        weekend_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (weekday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        event                   VARCHAR(50),
        UNIQUE td_ymd_idx (year,month,day),
        UNIQUE td_dbdate_idx (db_date)

) Engine=MyISAM;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN startdate DATE,IN stopdate DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentdate DATE;
    SET currentdate = startdate;
    WHILE currentdate < stopdate DO
        INSERT INTO time_dimension VALUES (
                        YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate),
                        currentdate,
                        YEAR(currentdate),
                        MONTH(currentdate),
                        DAY(currentdate),
                        QUARTER(currentdate),
                        WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%W'),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%M'),
                        'f',
                        CASE DAYOFWEEK(currentdate) WHEN 1 THEN 't' WHEN 7 then 't' ELSE 'f' END,
                        NULL);
        SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

TRUNCATE TABLE time_dimension;

CALL fill_date_dimension('1-01-01','2015-01-01');
OPTIMIZE TABLE time_dimension;
```

Comment: Beautiful! Solved my issue, otherwise i would have to spend 2-3 days doing hard labor work typing all the dates in. Thanks.